# Converting KML To Layer using ArcPy losing objects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, convert, kml

I am trying to a convert kml file to a layer using python.
This is my code:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion('C:\kml\\result.kml', 'C:\kml', 'result')
```

But the layer has lost a lot of objects as compared to the layer converted by *Conversion tools* -> *kmltolayer*

I attach 2 screenshots:

[image: layer, which was converted by Convertion tools -> kmltolayer]

[image: layer, which was converted by python script]

What could be the problem?

Comment: does the KML file meet these requirements "Point locations that use the address tag (by way of geocoding) are not supported. A valid latitude and longitude location is required inside the source KML." taken from ArcGIS help site.

Comment: Would you be able to include a screenshot of the KML To Layer tool dialog so that we can be sure that the same parameters have been used to create both screenshots (which are presumably of the output layer added to ArcMap), please?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112489/missing-raster-vector-layers-after-converting-kmz-using-kmltolayer-tool-of-arcgi - are you using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 too?