# Missing Raster/Vector Layers after converting KMZ using KMLToLayer tool of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, layers, kmz

I am trying to write a tool that will let users upload a KML/KMZ file and then be able to view it in a client application (something like an esri js api or Flex app).

I am ok with storing the data in a feature class (file, personal, sde) once it is uploaded.

I have tried writing a Python script using the KMLToLayer geoprocessing tool (I'm in 10.04) but I'm getting spotty results.

My test kmz has two vector layers and two raster layers but my output has only one vector layer and nothing else.

Are there other tools I could use?

Comment: I can't recall if the tool converted raster at 10.0 (I think it did, but limited support). Any chance you can use a newer version? The KML tools were greatly enhanced at 10.1/10.2 - you might get what you're after in a newer version.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to try and narrow down your issue which I think is that ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 appears not to be writing two raster and one vector layers from an input KMZ, and as @KHibma commented that may have been a software limitation at that version which has since been lifted.  The use of ArcGIS Server and JavaScript/Flex APIs does not seem to be involved in that specific question.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111656/converting-kml-to-layer-using-arcpy-losing-objects